# How to judge whether the current computer uses the apple M1 chip in the terminal?

Tags: macos

How to judge whether the current computer uses the M1 chip in the terminal?

And then I plan to execute different compilation scripts for different chips

Answer (score 6):

You can get the CPU information in terminal with

```
sysctl -n machdep.cpu.brand_string
```

Edit: The output is `Apple processor` or `Apple M1` / `Apple M1 Pro` on an Apple Silicon machine.

Comment: If anyone is running an M1-based system, maybe they'd be kind enough to add the output of vadian's command as a comment, for the sake of completeness. Thanks.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I would have if I owned one 

Comment: I guessed as much - your answers are always good and thorough.

Comment: On my Intel based Macbook Pro, this gives me `Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-9750H CPU @ 2.60GHz`.  On my M1-based Macbook Air this gives me: `Apple M1`

Comment: On my 2021 Macbook Pro, the output is `Apple M1 Pro`